# TableView titleForHeaderInSection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

My app shows this in the 4.3.1 simulator                   and this in the 5.0 simulator.

[image: 4.3.1 simulator][image: 5.0 simulator]

This is the code:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   return @""; 
}
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[Singleton sharedInstance] getTitleSectionView:segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex inDay:section];
}
-(UIView *)getTitleSectionView:(int)week inDay:(int)day;
{
UILabel *lab=[[[UILabel alloc]init]autorelease];
lab.frame=CGRectMake(5, 0,320,20);
lab.text=[[Singleton sharedInstance] getTitleSection:week inDay:day];
lab.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
lab.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
lab.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14];

UIImageView * imv = [[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 20)]autorelease];
imv.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"section-header-bg.png"];

UIView *view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 20)]autorelease];
[view addSubview:imv];
[view addSubview:lab];

    Week *currentWeek = nil;
    if(week)    
        currentWeek = nechetNedel;
    else        
        currentWeek = chetNedel;

    NSMutableArray *dayArray = [currentWeek.days objectAtIndex:day];
    if([dayArray count] >0)
        return view;
    return nil;
}
```

What can be the problem, why does lines of sections appear in the 5.0 simulator? I tried to delete the method `- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` but it did not help. I delete this method`(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` and the lines disappear

Comment: Show us `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`.

Comment: - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 7;
}

Comment: and now count the brownish and gray headers in the iOS 5 sim. You get it?

Comment: Matthias Bauch I do not quite understand

Comment: rokjarc  I can't correct number of section, example I have data in section 4, but return 1 count, in table will be first section

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should return nil for empty sections

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

and

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

should return 0

Then it will work. It is iOS 5.x issue (or feature)

Comment: - (UIView *)tableView: here I return nil and image for title not show, but show gray line, - (CGFloat)tableView: if here I return 0. I didn't see the image of this method - (UIView *)tableView:

Comment: it work, but why in IOS 4.3 it worked before, and in 5.0 not work, I can't understand

Comment: If you don't understand it then read the documentation. The release notes for iOS 5.0 quite clearly call this point out: "[In iOS 5] Returning nil from the tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: method (or its footer equivalent) is no longer sufficient to hide a header. You must override tableView:heightForHeaderInSection: and return 0.0 to hide a header."